conditional running header thymeleaf
I have a spring boot application that produces pdf from html template generated by SpringTemplateEngine and thymeleaf. The pdf is produced using com.openhtmltopdf.pdfboxout.PdfRendererBuilder
My issue is that I have a running header that appears in every page, and I need to hide it for some pages. The css looks like this
.header {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  position: running(header);
}

In the main template the header looks like this:
<div th:with="showHeader = true" class="header" th:if="${showHeader}">
  My Header
</div>

and i insert some other fragments in the main template:
<div th:each="item : ${items}">
  <div th:replace="~{summary :: 
  summary(summary=${item.summary})}"></div>
  <div th:replace="~{details :: 
  details(details=${item.details}, showHeader=${showHeader})}"></div>
</div>

in the details.html i need to hide the header for one of the nested fragments:
details.html:
<div class="page" th:fragment="details(details, showHeader)">
  ...
  <div th:each="result : ${service.getResults(detail.id)}">
    <div th:replace="~{resultTemplate :: result(result=${result}, showHeader=${showHeader})}"></div>
    </div>

</div>

and in the resultTemplate I need to hide the header
resultTemplate:
<div class="page" th:fragment="result(result, showHeader)"
 th:with="showHeader=false">

I have been stuck on this for a long time and could not achieve it. I tried displaying the value of showHeader in the resultTemplate and it shows false as expected, but the header is still there. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.
